# Finding the maximum of points in a given angle of circle

Tags: math, vector, 2d, geometry, points

I'm looking an algorithm which can determine the best angle (which represent the center of a circle sector) to get the maximum of points in this circle for a given sector size.

Example :

[image]

- Red is the sector (admit size is known).
- Green is the angle i want to find.
- Black points coordinates are known.

If I didn't explain correctly, ask it.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can "red" move? Or do you just want "green"? I think in any case all you have to do is get the angle for every "black" point and sort by that. It is really a 1D problem. Green would be the median. Red would be the origin of a range with the most points - just test starting from every point (there are probably better ways, but it's 1D)

Answer (score 0):

No there is not fixed number of sectors. Goal was to find the sector (by center angle) of given maximum angle having a maximum of points.

I found a solution algorithm to this.  thanks for help anyway. still think there are more efficient ways but i did like it :

- using atan2 to get angles for each points
- sorting points by angle
- associating points which are close enough to be in the sector maximum angle to the point checked (using a double for loop)
- returning the angle of the point with a maximum of associated points.

Tried to be clear but not really easy.
can post c++ sample if some of you are interested.